# Разбор учебного примера "калькулятор"

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с калькулятора 2 взять и добавить `id=type_design` в калькулятор 1 создав переменную, которая заменит цифру 450?http://learn.javascript.ru/play/z9I7C Буду очень признателен.

Comment: Вы хотите в "калькулятор 1" добавить select и сделать обработку его значений на JS?  
Постарайтесь сформулировать более конкретно

Comment: ДА, да, да